# c# sorting a list by the attributes of it's elements

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list `private List<Team> allTeams = new List<Team>() ;` 
 each Team from my list has a field `private double fitness ;` 
 
Could anybody explain to me please how `OrderBy<>` and `Sort` works and how I can use them to efficiently order my list `allTeams` by the `fitness` of each one ?

Comment: you can't with a private field

Comment: yes you can.If you override Equals and GetHashcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `fitness` a `public` or `internal` property `Fitness`.

Then use:

```
var ordered = allTeams.OrderBy(x => x.Fitness).ToList();
```

Comment: one question, will this sort apply to the original list `allTeams` ?

Comment: No, it will create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* don't want to expose `fitness`, you can:

1. Implement a custom [`IComparer<Team>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is *inside* your `Team` class but `public`, which uses its access to the private `fitness` field to compare the `fitness` of two teams.
2. Use this comparer in the [comparer overload of `Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), e.g.

```
var sortedTeams = allTeams.OrderBy(t => t, new Team.FitnessComparer());
```

or the [comparer overload of `List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sort in-place, e.g.

```
allTeams.Sort(new Team.FitnessComparer());
```

Comment: will this sort the original team ? or do I have to coppy the values from `sortedTeams` to `allTeams`?

Comment: This will create a new list and you'll need to replace the original list with it. You could use the [comparer-taking `List.Sort overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the same sort but in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) for you class.Then just use

```
allTeams.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Or

```
allTeams.Sort();
```

Comment: While this is correct, it's not massively intuitive to anybody then reading the code what the order would be by default.  Also not useful if you then subsequently want to order by number of team members for example.

Comment: Clever. Good solution. +1 (although Paddy is right this might be too much for OP)

Comment: Sorry, how will overriding `Equals` allow you to *order* the items? Knowing `1 != 2` doesn't let you order them.

Comment: @Paddy yes but it is also the only way to make it happen with a private field. unless you wanna implement a custom comparer that uses reflection

Comment: @Rawling you are right.  it should be IComparer<T> and you need to implement CompareTo method.

Comment: I think you mean `Comparable<T>` (or the other `OrderBy` overload`).

Answer (score 0):

If your fitness attribute was a public property you could do:

```
var ordered = allTeams.OrderBy(t => t.Fitness);
```

However, with a private field, you cannot do this.